# I kept getting Module Not Found Error in Jupyter. How do I solve this?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am getting this error after running my code in Jupyter Notebook using VS Code. I've checked at my Anaconda Prompt that I've already installed Numpy package.
[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dP2U.png)

Comment: Inside VSCode, `Ctrl+shift+P` to open the command palette, then "`>Python: Select Interpreter`" or "`>Notebook: select Notebook Kernel`" and choose the good conda environment.

Comment: What is "good conda environment" mean?

Comment: It is the one where you installed packages you are working with (`numpy` here).

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: Yeah, it is. I installed the numpy and other packages.

Answer (score 0):

If it says that there is no numpy, it means there is no numpy. You are probably in a virtual environment, or your conda and VS use different Python interpreters

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: @LuisPandiangan I am not very familiar with VS. Find where in settings your Python interpreter is and install numpy from there (at least this is how you do it in PyCharm).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Select the correct python interpreter in the upper right corner of the notebook.**

[image]

I deleted the `numpy` of the virtual environment, so now it reports an error.

I switched to conda environment (my conda environment has `numpy` package installed) and it works fine.

[image]